# Pandas self-merge blocked missing structure

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have this pandas data frame:

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2}, 'B': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.5}, 
'C1': {0: 9.0, 1: 9.0, 2: nan, 3: nan}, 'C2': {0: 9.0, 1: 9.0, 2: nan, 3: nan}, 'D1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 6.0, 3: 6.0}, 'D2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 6.0, 3: 6.0}}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The out come is:

```
   A    B   C1   C2   D1   D2
0  1  0.1  9.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
1  2  0.5  9.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
2  1  0.1  NaN  NaN  6.0  6.0
3  2  0.5  NaN  NaN  6.0  6.0
```

Now apparently this data frame can be consolidated, because it is unnecessarily blocked. The expected outcome is:

```
   A    B   C1   C2   D1   D2
0  1  0.1  9.0  9.0  6.0  6.0
1  2  0.5  9.0  9.0  6.0  6.0
```

In general I'm talking about a data frame that has most of the columns complete, or missing at random, but there exists this type of blocked non-random missing structure in the data frame that can be safely merged. The problem is we do not know in advance which columns are to be aggregated. How do deal with it?

Comment: `data.groupby('A',as_index=False).first()
`

Comment: Did this data come from a concat operation? Please use `axis=1`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks, but unfortunately it is not from concat. It is data I receive.

Comment: @Wen Thank you! But what if in advance I do not know which columns to group by? Here the group by should be all columns without this structure, that is, both A and B.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks a lot -- voted and accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending [Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139421/pandas-self-merge-blocked-missing-structure/50139656#comment87297210_50139421), you'll need to determine what columns aren't null, and then `groupby` on those:

```
data.groupby(
   data.columns[data.notnull().all()].tolist(), as_index=False
).first()

   A    B   C1   C2   D1   D2
0  1  0.1  9.0  9.0  6.0  6.0
1  2  0.5  9.0  9.0  6.0  6.0
```